# Git squash and merge

Tags: git, merge, squash

Could anyone please tell me what the difference between these two commands:

```
git merge --squash
```

and

```
git merge --no-ff
```

Comment: I corrected the argument order on your question, since it doesn't seem to be the main point of the question and dealing with it adds unnecessary noise in the answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your question indicates a bit of a misunderstanding. `--no-ff` and `--squash` are not opposites, rather they are subtly different operations. Keep that in mind while reading.

### git merge --squash

The [help page for merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) says the following about `--squash`:

> `--squash` and `--no-squash`
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually
>   make a commit or move the HEAD, nor record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD to
>   cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit. This
>   allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch
>   whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of
>   an octopus).
>
> With --no-squash perform the merge and commit the result. This option
>   can be used to override --squash.

That's a bit confusing, and requires some knowledge about the internals of `git`. To start, we need to understand the difference between a regular commit and a merge commit. A regular commit has one parent, and is simply a changeset to apply to the commit before it:

```
A --> B --> C
```

A merge commit has multiple parents, and it a place in the tree where you've brought two or more lineages together:

```
A --> B --> F
           /
C --> D - /
```

See how `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are regular commits, but `F` is a merge commit, since it has multiple parents (`B` and `D`)? This is what `git merge --no-ff` would produce. It forces Git to create a merge commit to bring two histories together.

`git merge --squash` would do something a little different. It prevents Git from creating a merge commit, but still pulls in the changes `C` and `D` made, so your tree looks like this:

```
A --> B --> F'

C --> D
```

`F'` contains changes `C` and `D` made, but there's no sign of the fact you merged two trees in the repository.

### git merge --no-ff

`--no-ff` is a slightly different operation. It forces Git into creating a merge commit even if it's not really necessary. For reference, here's what the manual has to say about `--no-ff` and it's opposite `--ff-only`:

> `--no-ff`
>
> Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward.
>
> `--ff-only`
>
> Refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status unless the current HEAD is already up-to-date or the merge can be resolved as a
>   fast-forward.

To understand, it's best to look at an example:

```
A --> B --> C --> D --> E
      |                 |
    'master'          'topic'
```

If you had this tree, were on the master branch, and ran `git merge`, Git would perform what's called a "fast-forward" merge. Since there's no divergence between the two histories, Git can just move the `master` branch up to where `topic` sits without doing anything interesting. It would look like this:

```
A --> B --> C --> D --> E
                        |
                     'topic'
                     'master'
```

With both topic and master pointing to the same branch. Now, some workflow policies require that you create a merge commit every time you merge back into `master`. This keeps the history of branches around. You'll get arguments either way on how it should be done, but I won't get into those here.

If you used `git merge --no-ff` on that same tree instead, it would force git to create a merge commit, giving you a tree like this:

```
                   'master'
                       |
A --> B -------------> F
       \              /
        C --> D --> E
                    |
                 'topic'
```

Where `F` is the new merge commit `--no-ff` force Git to create.